# Masstransit - Courier catch exception in consumer

Tags: masstransit

I used a courier for my project, created an activity, everything works fine, if an exception occurs inside the activity, then the compensation will work and it's good for me. But if not in this activity (there is a publish or send in the activity) and in another microservice there is a consumer, in this consumer I want to receive an exception and, accordingly, compensation, but this will not work for me at all. How to make it so that the activity could catch the exception in the consumer in a different microservice.

Comment: Could you clarify your question, perhaps with a diagram or something? I'm unable to track what it is you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: This is your demo registration project in which I added a billing project to the same project I added a consumer in order to get an exception. Code in gitlab https://gitlab.com/skay3922/demo-registration

Comment: I added a screenshot of the result of the courier to README.md in gitlab

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you modify the ProcessPayment activity to call another message-based API, you should use the `IRequestClient` to send the request to the API, and then handle the response and either fault the activity or complete it. That way, the choreography is handled by the activity.

As it exists in that sample, the activity is calling Publish and then continuing as if everything completed. That isn't the case if the card consumer throws an exception.

Comment: Ok thanks, I'll try to use IRequestClient, I'll write how it goes

Comment: Thank you very much Chris you helped me a lot. The IRequestClient returns an exception and the courier compensates for the data. And another question is the courier provides ACID, namely data isolation, that is, when one request changes the data of the second and subsequent requests could not change the first one, it must block (this is like in a local transaction). I wanted to say, for example, several microservices started one transaction so that at that time there should be data isolation in all microservices. If this is in masstransit courier.